# WooCommerce Displaying Price With & Without TAX

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to display prices both with and without tax on my products.

My solution so far is to add the code below to the /woocommerce/single-product/price.php template file.

```
<p class="price"><?php echo wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ); ?> incl. VAT | <?php echo wc_price( wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ) ); ?> ex. VAT </p>
```

It works for the most part but not on variable products.

Does anyone have any other solutions?